# Auto Load data in Qlik Sense Desktop or enterprise version

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Is there possibilities to auto load data in QLik Sense ?
Explanation - Usually I open Qlik Sense desktop daily and go to app -> data load editor -> select Load data.

I do this daily to update dashboard. Is it possible to auto load data with same path and same destination folder. So that I don't always select load data button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automated reloads are not available through Qlik Sense Desktop or Cloud but if you use entreprise there is a Scheduler Service that allows you to do this easily in QMC

> http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/June2017/Subsystems/ManagementConsole/Content/create-reload-tasks.htm